# how equals method works internally

Tags: java

I have a student class and I have overridden the equals method and hash code. How equals method internally checking all the objects of the student type. As per the below code, how all instance (s1,s2,s3,s4)of the student class is compared. The code implementation is comparing this and inserted object. As per my understanding "this" refers to all the reference variables of a class. But how without any iteration, all the references are getting compared.

Student.java

```
public class Student {


    private String regNumber;

    public Student(String regNum) {

        this.regNumber=regNum;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((regNumber == null) ? 0 : regNumber.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        System.out.println("this "+this.getRegNumber());
        System.out.println("obj "+obj.toString());

        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (regNumber == null) {
            if (other.regNumber != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!regNumber.equals(other.regNumber))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public String getRegNumber() {
        return regNumber;
    }

    public void setRegNumber(String regNumber) {
        this.regNumber = regNumber;
    }

}
```

App.java

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 =new Student("A1");
        Student s2 =new Student("A2");
        Student s3 =new Student("A1");
        Student s4 =new Student("A1");
        Student s5 =new Student("A4");

        s1.equals(s1);

        HashMap<Student, String> studentMap=new HashMap<Student, String>();
        studentMap.put(s1, "bob");
        studentMap.put(s2, "mary");
        studentMap.put(s3, "eva");
        studentMap.put(s4, "rob");
        studentMap.put(s5, "alex");


        System.out.println(studentMap.size());



    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. What do you mean 'internally'? **You've** written the implementation. How did you write it if you don't understand it?

Comment: “*As per my understanding "this" refers to all the reference variables of a class*”— **No**, `this` refers to one particular instance of your class. It’s `equals` method does precisely what you’ve written into it, i.e. it will perform a comparison of `regNumber` and nothing else, as that’s what has written in the code. And there is no code “*checking all the objects of the student type*”. You are creating an instance of `HashMap` and that’s the class containing an algorithm for checking its contained keys for equality (though it’s hashing is there to avoid having to check all of them).

Comment: @Michael perhaps, the IDE generated these methods.

Comment: put a break point where you .equals is, and then run the code in debug. you can then follow it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand why it is worth implementing `equals` in the first place. When you do a comparison on primitive types like integers, it's quite obvious how they are compared. Java doesn't need any help telling whether `1==1`. But, for a class you create yourself like `Student` java has no idea what equality means. The only thing it can check on its own is *reference equality*; that is, whether or not two variables point to the same object in memory. This is usually not helpful however, so instead we must write our own method and define when two objects are equal by inspecting the internal details of each. (If you already knew all that, apologies but might as well be thorough)

It seems that your `Student` class has defined equality to be true whenever two `Student` objects have the same `regNumber`.

Let's go through what it's doing step by step:

```
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
```

`this` refers to **the reference to the current instance of the `Student` object  invoking this method**. In other words, it is nothing but the pointer to the object.  So, this if statement is performing a check that is saying: "If this object reference and the object reference passed in point to the same object, return true." In effect this saves us the trouble of comparing any of their internal details, because if two objects pass reference equality they must be equal.

```
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
```

Pretty self explanatory. If the other object reference passed in is null it can't possibly equal this object, so return false.

```
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
```

This line performs a comparison based on class types. So, if this object (a `Student`) is not the same class type as the passed in object, again they can't be equal so return false.

```
    Student other = (Student) obj;
    if (regNumber == null) {
        if (other.regNumber != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!regNumber.equals(other.regNumber))
        return false;
    return true;
```

Now for the real meat of the comparison. First, we cast the `Object` passed in back to a `Student` type. Then, compare the `regNumber` of each object (first confirming that neither is `null` to avoid a `NullPointerException`. If they are not equal we return false, otherwise return true.

Do note that if you were to add more fields to `Student`, they will be ignored as far as equality is concerned, unless you were to add a way to consider them into your `equals` method. That is to say, fields are not "automatically iterated through", you must manually and deliberately add all fields that should be considered relevant for object equality.